# How to recognize whether is it successfully find the values for the 'asserEquals' in Selenium(POM)?

Tags: eclipse, selenium, testing, automated-tests

Here mentioned code successfully passed by the test run.But it was not showed the login button click and the logged-user name.(I have try to print the messages by try-catch ).but result shows as passed without those messages.

I just wanted to why can't I see the button click and assertEqual messages?
is there any coding issue or practice should be able to use to overcome this?

I have used the xml file to send the browser type.Further,I pasted only the relevant code sections.

1.TestCommands.java

```
public class TestCommands {
public void assertText(By locator,WebDriver driver,String expectedValue){
try {
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(locator);
    assertEquals(element.getText(), expectedValue);         
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("Not equal");
}
System.out.println("Equal");
System.out.println("captured web element: "+ locator);
System.out.println("captured expectedValue: "+ expectedValue);
}
}
```

2.LoginPage.java

```
public class LoginPage extends TestCommands{
public void loginToApplication(WebDriver driver,String userName,String  password,String loggedUser){
type(userName(),driver,userName);
type(password(),driver,password);
click(loginButton(),driver);
selectByVisibleText(loggedUser(),driver,loggedUser);
```

}

3.TC_LoginToTest.java

```
public class TC_LoginToTest {
 WebDriver driver ;
 String baseUrl;
 LoginPage login = new LoginPage(); 

@Parameters("browser")
@BeforeMethod
 public void beforeMethod(String browser) {

   if (browser.equals("firefox")) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "drivers\\geckodriver.exe");
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    //baseUrl = "https://test.com";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   } else if (browser.equals("chrome")) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    //baseUrl = "https://test.com";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
   }
 }  
 @DataProvider
 public Object[][] tc001() {
 return new Object[][] {
        new Object[] {"nadee","12345678","Testnadee"},      
 };
}

 @Test(dataProvider="tc001")
  public void tc001(String userName , String password ,String loggedUser)        { 
    login.openApplication("https://test.com", driver);
    login.loginToApplication(driver, userName, password, loggedUser);
  }
 }
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No actually i didnt get any error,but cannot be able to see the button click and going to the dashboad username(logged).thats confusing me whether it worked properly or not... @YosuvaA

Comment: Actually it worked.That is the reason it going to Dashboard. Isn't it?

Comment: If you want to see the object highlight with red box , I can help you

Comment: No i meant it is not going to the dashboard.(even not showing the button click,before that)thats what confuses me about the 'passed' results...@YosuvaA

Comment: Can I get your application URL also the code of  loginButton()?

Comment: @YosuvaA I dont have any permission to give the application URL since it belongs to the company which im working for.                                   public By loginButton(){
  return By.xpath("(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='SIGN IN'])[1]/following::div[2]");
 }

Comment: Can you add the html code screenshot into your question?